Relate lines drawn from points on major axis of ellipse
In the attached drawing I would like to relate p and q.  p is the line drawn from S to T (angle $\kappa$ and q is the line drawn from $S_{HP}$ to T (angle $\phi$). Using w and $b_{HP}$ I can write the following equations
$$p = \frac{y}{sin\kappa}$$
$$q = \frac{y}{sin\phi}$$
$$p = \frac{x+w}{cos\kappa}$$
$$q = \frac{x+b_{HP}}{cos\phi}$$
But if I take the ratio of p/q, that ratio will fail at $0$ and $180$ degrees if I use the sin expressions and at $90$ degrees if I use the cosine expressions.  Is there a way I can rewrite the equations (or perhaps use other equations) so that I can alway have a value for the ratio of p/q as a function of either $\phi$ or $\kappa$ or both.
EDIT:  I should have stated that $S_{HP}$ is a focus of the ellipse, but S is not.
EDIT #2: NOTE: Below I substituted $b$ for $b_{HP}$. Since pt. $S_{HP}$ is a focus, then
$$q=\frac{R sin\theta}{1-cos\theta cos\phi}$$
and
$$p^2 = (x+w)^2 + y^2$$
$$q^2 = (x+b)^2 + y^2$$
Multiplying $p^2$ out and substituting for $y^2$ from $q^2$ equation,
$$p^2 = x^2+w^2+2xw +q^2-(x^2+b^2+2xb) = q^2+w^2-b^2+2x(w-b)$$
Now I just need to get rid of x.  I could substitute in
$$x=q\cos\phi-b$$
That yields,
$$p^2 = q^2+w^2-b^2+2(qcos\phi-b)(w-b)$$
$p^2$ and $q^2$ are okay (as opposed to having the final expression in p and q). It would be nice to have the expression in more compact form.


From your equations, I guess $(x,y)$ are the coordinates of $T$.
Then $p = \sqrt{(x+w)^2+y^2}$ and $q = \sqrt{(x+b_{HP})^2 + y^2}$.
If you don't know all four of the quantities $x$, $y$, $w$, and $b_{HP}$, please state specifically which quantities are known that you want to compute $p$ and $q$ from.

I notice that from $R$ and $\theta$ you can compute the value of $b_{HP}$, and if you also know $\phi$ you can then compute $x$ and $y$. Then, in most cases, knowing $\kappa$ you can compute $w$. But if $\kappa=0$ or $\kappa=180^\circ$ then there is no way to determine the position of $S$ from any of the named quantities except $w$. The fact that you fail to find a ratio there may be a limitation of the problem statement that cannot be overcome by a "better" set of equations.

So, as I added to the original post, $S_{HP}$ is a focus.  That means that q is equal to:
$$q=\frac{R sin\theta}{1-cos\theta cos\phi}$$
This eqn. for q will not create issues if $\phi$ is 0 or 90 or 180 degrees.  So, I think if I need to figure out how movement from $S_{HP}$ to S impacts p.  If $S = S_{HP}$ then p = q.  So, it seems like w and $b_{HP}$ could be the parameters I need to work with.  I always know the value of $\theta$ and it is never equal to 0 degrees or greater than 90 degrees. Any thoughts.

See Edit#2 made to original post.

I assume here that $R$, $\theta$, and $w$ are known quantities.
In addition, $b_{HP}$ is determined by $R$ and $\theta$ (see below) so I assume that is known also.
Starting with your equation
$$ p^2 = q^2+w^2-b_{HP}^2+2(q\cos\phi-b_{HP})(w-b_{HP}), $$
we have
\begin{align}
p^2 &= q^2 + w^2 - b_{HP}^2 + 2(q\cos\phi - b_{HP})(w - b_{HP}) \\
&= q^2 + w^2 - b_{HP}^2 - 2wb_{HP} + 2b_{HP}^2 + 2q\cos\phi(w - b_{HP}) \\
&= q^2 + (w - b_{HP})^2 + 2q(w - b_{HP})\cos\phi. \\
\end{align}
Divide through by $q^2$:
$$
\frac{p^2}{q^2} = 1 + \frac{(w - b_{HP})^2}{q^2}
 + \frac{2(w - b_{HP})\cos\phi}{q}
$$
Use the formula you found,
$$ q = \frac{R\sin\theta}{1 - \cos\theta \cos\phi}, $$
to replace the two instances of $q$ on the right-hand side and take the square root of both sides in order to get an expression for $p/q$ in terms of the known quantities.
(No need to be concerned about choosing positive or negative square roots;
$p/q$ is positive.)

Just for completeness, here are my proofs of your formulas.
In the usual terminology of ellipses, $\frac R{\sin\theta}$ is the semimajor axis of the ellipse, usually denoted by the symbol $a$;
$R$ is the semiminor axis, usually denoted by the symbol $b$.
The usual notation $b$ for semiminor axis conflicts with your use of $b$ in the question, so I will use $b_{HP}$, not $b$, for the distance marked $b_{HP}$ in the diagram.
The distance $b_{HP}$ is half the interfocal distance, usually denoted $c$.
If an ellipse has semiaxis lengths $a$ and $b$ and semi-interfocal distance $c$, then $c^2 = a^2 - b^2$. In your notation,
$$ b_{HP}^2 = \left(\frac R{\sin\theta}\right)^2 - R^2
= \frac{1 - \sin^2\theta}{\sin^2\theta}R^2 = R^2 \cot^2\theta. $$
Assuming that $b_{HP}$ is non-negative and $0 < \theta < 90^\circ$,
it follows that $b_{HP} = R \cot\theta$.
From Wikipedia,
the equation of an ellipse in polar coordinates $(r,\phi)$ such that the origin is at the left focus of the ellipse is
$$ r = \frac{a(1 - e^2)}{1 - e \cos\phi} $$
where $e = \frac ca$. 
Applying this to your diagram, taking $S_{HP}$ as the origin of the polar coordinate system, we have $q = r$, $a = \frac R{\sin\theta}$, and
$e = \frac{R\cot\theta}{R/\sin\theta} = \cos\theta$, so
$$
q = \frac{\frac R{\sin\theta}(1 - \cos\theta^2)}{1 - \cos\theta \cos\phi}
= \frac{R\sin\theta}{1 - \cos\theta \cos\phi},
$$
as you observed.
For $q$, observe that $SS_{HP}T$ is a triangle with sides $p$, $q$, and
$w - b_{HP}$, whose exterior angle at $S_{HP}$ (opposite side $p$) is $\phi$. The cosine of the interior angle is therefore $-\cos{\phi}$ and the law of cosines gives us
$$ p^2 = q^2 + (w - b_{HP})^2 + 2q(w - b_{HP})\cos\phi, $$
which as we see above is equivalent to your formula for $p^2$.
